# SVG not taking full width on internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, cross-browser

I'm loading SVG map using JQuery Ajax in my website that is working fine on all browsers except internet explorer. its not taking full width in internet explorer, I tried to add width 100% using CSS but didn't work.

I attached bellow SVG view on different browsers and SVG code for better understanding.

[image]

```
       <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" 
        viewBox="-279 414.72 35.58 13.17" style="enable-background:new -279 
        414.72 35.58 13.17;"xml:space="preserve">
        ....</svg>
```

Thanks

Comment: We can't debug an image, we need a working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 3):

The thing with Internet Explorer is that it requires a **Height** in pixels to work.
If you put a normal **svg** image and you want to make it "responsive" you need to work with percentages:

```
<div id="some_div">
   <svg id="my_svg">...</svg>
</div>

<style>
   #my_svg {
      max-width: 500px; /*--- just added this to limit the width ---*/
      width: 100%;
      height: auto; /*--- or you can even avoid putting the "height"---*/
   }
</style>
```

The code will work fine in most browsers, but IE won't know the size so it will make the image very small. You need to declare the height size of your image:

```
<style>
   #my_svg {
      max-width: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 350px; /*--- supposing the height  of you svg is 350px---*/
   }
</style>
```

This way your image will take the size you are looking. The only bad thing is that everytime you reduce the size of the browser there will be a "blank space" around your image, this because the width (100%) will change but the height will stay 350 pixels. You may want to erase those blank spaces with some **@medias** every time the browser's screen reduces the size:

```
<div id="some_div">
   <svg id="my_svg">...</svg>
</div>

<style>
   #my_svg {
      max-width: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 350px;
   }
   @media (max-width: 1100px) {
      #my_svg {
         height: 250px;
      }
   }
   @media (max-width: 900px) {
      #my_svg {
         height: 150px;
      }
   }
   ...
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  It's pretty ugly though.  Does anyone have a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have loaded your SVG inside an image tag, and are not targeting correctly using CSS.

This targets every  tag with src that ends in ".svg" in IE10, and IE11: from [Fix SVG in  tags not scaling in IE9, IE10, IE11](https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/7881691) via [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg)

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: 
none) {
 img[src$=".svg"] {
   width: 100%; 
 }
}
```

IE does not respect ratios of SVG images inside  tags in fluid layouts. All other browsers scale SVG images as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this workaround, which is working for me and avoids having to use a bunch of media queries:

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <svg>
       ...
    </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 61%; (corresponding to the aspect ratio of your SVG)
    position: relative;
}    

svg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```